# How can I cancel war deployment on specific conditions in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war

I have to implement a special conditions check in the existing WAR application deployed in Tomcat 7. I have created a Servlet that perform necessary checks on it's init() method. So, during WAR startup everything is being checked.

Now, if I want the WAR application to be accessible **only** when all the conditions are met and some condition did not work - how can I stop the deployment of the WAR? In the other words how can I prevent access to the WAR application?

As an example of such condition: for example, I found that the database is not properly updated and therefore application will crash on attempt to access the DB.